# MongoDB nested query using aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection "superpack", which has the nested objects. The sample document looks like below.

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56038c8cca689261baca93eb"),
  "name": "Test sub",
  "packs": [
  {
  "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cead",
  "name": "Classic",
  "packDispVal": "PACK",
  "billingPts": [
    {
      "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3ceab",
      "name": "Classic 1 month",
      "expiryVal": 1,
      "amount": 20,
      "topUps": [
        {
          "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9",
          "name": "1 extra",
          "amount": 8
        },
        {
          "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3ceaa",
          "name": "2 extra",
          "amount": 12
        }
      ]
    },
  {
      "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3ceac",
      "name": "Classic 2 month",
      "expiryVal": 1,
      "amount": 30,
      "topUps": [
        {
          "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea8",
          "name": "3 extra",
          "amount": 16
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
  ]
}
```

I need to query for the nested object topups with the id field and result should have only the selected topup object and its associated parent. I am expecting the output to like below, when i query it on topup id 55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9.

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56038c8cca689261baca93eb"),
  "name": "Test sub",
  "packs": [
    {
      "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cead",
      "name": "Classic",
      "packDispVal": "PACK",
      "billingPts": [
        {
          "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3ceab",
          "name": "Classic 1 month",
          "expiryVal": 1,
          "amount": 20,
          "topUps": [
            {
              "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9",
              "name": "1 extra",
              "amount": 8
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with the below aggregate query for the same. However its not returning any result. Can you please help me, what is wrong in the query?

```
db.superpack.aggregate( [{ $match: { "id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9" } }, { $redact: {$cond: {   if: { $eq: [ "$id", "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9" ]  },   "then": "$$KEEP",   else: "$$PRUNE" }}} ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)  is not a viable option here based on the fact that with the recursive `$$DESCEND` it is basically looking for a field called "id" at all levels of the document. You cannot possibly ask to do this only at a specific level of embedding as it's all or nothing.

This means you need alternate methods of filtering the content rather than `$redact`. All "id" values are unique so their is no problem filtering via "set" operations.

So the most efficient way to do this is via the following:

```js
db.docs.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "packs.billingPts.topUps.id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9"
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "packs": {
            "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                    "input": "$packs",
                    "as": "pack",
                    "in": {
                        "$let": {
                            "vars": {
                                "billingPts": {
                                    "$setDifference": [
                                        { "$map": {
                                            "input": "$$pack.billingPts",
                                            "as": "billing",
                                            "in": {
                                                "$let": {
                                                    "vars": {
                                                        "topUps": {
                                                            "$setDifference": [
                                                                { "$map": {
                                                                    "input": "$$billing.topUps",
                                                                    "as": "topUp",
                                                                    "in": {
                                                                        "$cond": [
                                                                            { "$eq": [ "$$topUp.id", "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9" ] },
                                                                            "$$topUp",
                                                                            false
                                                                        ]
                                                                    }
                                                                }},
                                                                [false]
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "in": {
                                                        "$cond": [
                                                            { "$ne": [{ "$size": "$$topUps"}, 0] },
                                                            {
                                                                "id": "$$billing.id",
                                                                "name": "$$billing.name",
                                                                "expiryVal": "$$billing.expiryVal",
                                                                "amount": "$$billing.amount",
                                                                "topUps": "$$topUps"
                                                            },
                                                            false
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }},
                                        [false]
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$ne": [{ "$size": "$$billingPts"}, 0 ] },
                                    { 
                                        "id": "$$pack.id",
                                        "name": "$$pack.name",
                                        "packDispVal": "$$pack.packDispVal",
                                        "billingPts": "$$billingPts"
                                    },
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }},
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Where after digging down to the innermost array that is being filtered, that then the size of each resulting array going outwards is tested to see if it is zero, and omitted from results where it is.

It's a long listing but it is the most efficient way since each array is filtered down first and within each document.

A not so efficient way is to pull apart with `$unwind` and the `$group` back the results:

```js
db.docs.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "packs.billingPts.topUps.id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$packs" },
    { "$unwind": "$packs.billingPts" },
    { "$unwind": "$packs.billingPts.topUps"},
    { "$match": {
        "packs.billingPts.topUps.id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9"
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "_id": "$_id",
            "packs": {
                "id": "$packs.id",
                "name": "$packs.name",
                "packDispVal": "$packs.packDispVal",
                "billingPts": {
                    "id": "$packs.billingPts.id",
                    "name": "$packs.billingPts.name",
                    "expiryVal": "$packs.billingPts.expiryVal",
                    "amount": "$packs.billingPts.amount"
                }
            }
        },
        "topUps": { "$push": "$packs.billingPts.topUps" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id._id",
            "packs": {
                "id": "$_id.packs.id",
                "name": "$_id.packs.name",
                "packDispVal": "$_id.packs.packDispVal"
            }
        },
        "billingPts": { 
            "$push": {
                "id": "$_id.packs.billingPts.id",
                "name": "$_id.packs.billingPts.name",
                "expiryVal": "$_id.packs.billingPts.expiryVal",
                "amount": "$_id.packs.billingPts.amount",
                "topUps": "$topUps"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "packs": {
            "$push": {
                "id": "$_id.packs.id",
                "name": "$_id.packs.name",
                "packDispVal": "$_id.packs.packDispVal",
                "billingPts": "$billingPts"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

The listing looks a lot more simple but of course there is a lot of overhead introduced by `$unwind` here. The process of grouping back is basically keeping a copy of everything outside of the current array level being reconstructed, and then push that content back into the array in the next stage, until you get back to the root `_id`.

Please note that unless you intend such a search to match more than one document or if you are going to have significant gains from reduced network traffic by effectively reducing down the response size from a very large document, then it would be advised to do neither of these but follow much of the same design as the first pipeline example but in client code.

Whilst the first example would be still okay performance wise, it's still a mouthful to send to the server and as a general listing, that is typically written with the same operations in a cleaner way in client code to process and filter the resulting structure.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56038c8cca689261baca93eb"),
    "packs" : [
            {
                    "id" : "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cead",
                    "name" : "Classic",
                    "packDispVal" : "PACK",
                    "billingPts" : [
                            {
                                    "id" : "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3ceab",
                                    "name" : "Classic 1 month",
                                    "expiryVal" : 1,
                                    "amount" : 20,
                                    "topUps" : [
                                            {
                                                    "id" : "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea9",
                                                    "name" : "1 extra",
                                                    "amount" : 8
                                            }
                                    ]
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am new to MongoDB. Is there any performance hit if i achieve this, just by using the unwind and match. I tried with the below query.

db.doc.aggregate([{$unwind: "$packs"}, {$unwind : "$packs.billingPts"}, {$unwind:"$packs.billingPts.topUps"}, {$match : { "packs.billingPts.topUps.id": "55fbc7f6b0ce97a309b3cea8"}}])

Comment: @Girish Part of the explaination here is that there is potentially a very large hit when processing with `$unwind` and hence why filtering the arrays inline is shown first. You should really try to only use `$unwind` when it is your intention to aggregate across documents and not just for filtering content from matched documents, and even then you really should filter first. Unwinding creates a copy of the document for each array member, so this exponentially increases the documents to process. Also **always** `$match` first, as this removes documents that would not meet the conditions.